# ¿Cómo guardar un select múltiple en una llave foránea?

Tags: php, html, sql

Resulta que tengo una base de datos relacional donde tengo una tabla de **horario de trabajo**.

> idhora int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
>   nombreH varchar(60)
>   horaEntrada varchar(60)
>   horaSalida varchar(60)
>   dias_semanales varchar(60)

Y tengo otra tabla de Usuarios donde **idhora** es llave foranea, en la cual la relación es uno a muchos, donde un usuario puede tener varios horarios de trabajo.

> idusuario int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
>   nombre varchar(60)
>   apellidop varchar(60)
>   apellidom varchar(60)
>   idhora int(11) foreing key

**El problema es que en tengo que usar un select Múltiple, el cual los datos seleccionados se deben guardar en la tabla Usuarios en el campo idhora, pero solo almacena un valor. Alguien me puede ayudar, por favor??**

Este es el código que uso en el formulario donde traigo el nombre de los horarios de trabajo.

```
    <?php 
          $sql1="SELECT idhora, nombreH FROM hora_trabajo"; 
          $query = $mysqli->query($sql1);?> 
            <label style="font-family: Arial;"> Horarios de Trabajo:</label>

    <select id="dates-field2" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple" name="idhora[]">
              <?php 
             while($lista=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
                echo "<option  value='".$lista["idhora"]."'>".$lista["nombreH"]."</option>"; 

        ?>
</select>
```

**Insertando el arreglo**

```
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$apellidop=$_POST['apellidop'];
$apellidom=$_POST['apellidom'];
$idhora = "" . implode(",", $_POST['idhora']) . "";
$sql ="INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellidop, apellidom,idhora) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellidop','$apellidom','$idhora')";
$resultado = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $sql);
if (!$resultado){
  alert("ERROR AL REGISTRAR USUARIO");
}
else{
  alert("USUARIO REGISTRADO CON EXITO");
}mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

**Cualquier ayuda es valiosa gracias...**

Comment: creo que el esquema de bbdd que trabajas es incorrecto. Estas definiendo un idHora en la tabla Usuarios, por lo que un usuario solo puede tener una hora (y una hora puede ser de varios usuarios). Creo que deberia ser al reves: en tu tabla Hora deberias tener un id de Usuario, y en el de usuario no tendrias el de hora. De todas formas, el caso que quieres trabajar suele ser **many-to-many**, y necesitarias una tabla intermedia para la relacion usuario-hora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno el problema es como definimos el Select multiple y como me llegan esos datos por POST para lo quedes de entender que es un Array y para hacer esto según la relación de tu base de datos debes de hacer un recorrido por for

`$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$apellidop=$_POST['apellidop'];
$apellidom=$_POST['apellidom'];
$idhora = $_POST['idhora']);
for ($i=0;$i< count($idhora);$i++){

  $sql ="INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellidop, apellidom,idhora) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellidop','$apellidom','$idhora[$i]')";
  $resultado = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $sql);
  //inventa nuevo metodo de alerta 
} 
mysqli_close($mysqli);`

Te sugiero que revises la relación, para mi la mas adecuada y optima es de Muchos a Muchos y trata de que en la tabla Usuarios se maneje otro campo como documentoUsuario que te permite así unificar estos múltiples registros en consultas futuras.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho tu respuesta!! ;-)